# How to add a confirmation dialog when deleting any item in finder

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, filesystem, macos

Hi would like to add a "Are you sure?" prompt when deleting an item (file, folder) from the finder (like the one when emptying the trash...). 
Can this be enabled?

Comment: I would try an Automator folder action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just lock it!

Right click the item and **Get info**, or select the item and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

[image][image]

Comment: Nice, but I'm rather looking for a global solution...

Comment: This is it my friend, you might want to update the original question though.

Comment: Done : from 'an item' to 'any item'

Answer (score 0):

You may configure a folder action:

1. Enable view all files:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true ; killall Finder
   ```
2. Navigate to your user folder
3. Right-click the usually invisible Trash folder and choose Services -> Folder Actions Setup...
4. Add a new folder action by hitting the +-sign below the right pane and add the script "add - new item alert.scpt". You may change the script by hitting the button "Edit Script" (e.g. replacing the standard message by "Are you sure?"). If you want to keep the original file "add - new item alert.scpt" make a duplicate, rename it to an arbitrary name and modify it. The script resides in /Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts
5. Hit the radio button "Enable Folder Actions".
6. Disable view all files:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean false ; killall Finder
   ```

In my Yosemite VM the folder action is slightly unresponsive and the alert occurs not until after 2-3 seconds.